# How can I pass environment variables to Apache via nginx proxypass?

Tags: nginx

This is what I use to do a proxy_pass:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

After this $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is no longer available in php. What do I need to do to have these $_SERVER variables available in php after nginx passes request to Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have mod_rpaf installed in Apache and in Nginx, add the following:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: Are there other headers I should be sending? like rest of the $_SERVER vars? Where is this in documentation, can you point me to a resource please?

Comment: I don't think you will find a reference in the Nginx docs saying "this is how you should proxy to Apache". However, by understanding how both wedservers work, you will see that need mod_rpaf active and for the remote ip to be passed by nginx as stated, to properly get those specific items through to Apache. Have a read up on mod_rpaf. As for the rest of the $_SERVER vars, there is nothing special that needs to be done. Actually, are you suggesting that your $_SERVER vars have totally disappeared and not that the remote ip is incorrectly transmitted?

Comment: I just checked and looks like all the variables are actually being passed/available. I guess mor_rpaf is already running. The issue I guess that I'm having is that because I'm forwarding, REMOTE_ADDR is 127.0.0.1. Is there a way I can "override" this value with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?

Comment: Yes, there is ... install mod_rpaf and pass the headers as stated.